# connect windows remote desktop without login prompt

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, authentication

When I connect from one Windows machine to another with RDP, it prompts me for my login name and password and offers to save them. How do I just have it send my current login credentials for the machine I'm on? i.e. like it does when I connect to a SQL Server instance with SSMS and have it use integrated auth.

*note:* my user is a domain user

Comment: The Windows RDP client doesn't support this method of authentication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save credentials.  If you save the connection as an RPD file, and use that file to initiate the connection, you can specify in options for the connection "Allow me to save credentials".  It will prompt you the first time then shouldn't afterwards.  It's possible your domain is set up in such a way that you can't save the credentials at all.